# Jquery .removeClass not working inside setTimeout

Tags: jquery, navigation, hover, settimeout, removeclass

so I have a drop down navigation that appears on hover and I'm trying to get a delay in there to improve usability. Originally I was using hoverIntent which worked beautifully everywhere except on IE8 and below.

So instead I'm trying to do the delay with plain old Javascript but the setTimeout function won't call my jQuery.

var J = jQuery.noConflict();

```
 J(".navigation li").hover(function(){J(this).addClass("hover");},function(){setTimeout("J(this).removeClass('hover');",500);});
```

When I set it up like this:

```
 function off(){J(this).removeClass("hover"); alert("hello");}


J(".navigation li").hover(function(){J(this).addClass("hover");},function(){setTimeout("off()",500);});
```

The alert works perfectly but not the .removeClass function.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The value of `this` in your "off()" function won't be what you need it to be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` inside `setTimeout` is not the li element; i recommend you to use setTimeout overload that receives a function, and before set a variable to `this` to keep a reference:

```
J(".navigation li").hover(function(){
   J(this).addClass("hover");
},
function(){
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
         J(self).removeClass('hover');
  },500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `off` function:

```
function off() {
    J(this).removeClass("hover");
    alert("hello")
}
```

won't have the right `this` variable when called by `setTimeout()` - on most (all?) browsers it sets `this` to `window`.

You need an additional closure to wrap the original `this` and pass it to that timer function:

```
J(".navigation li").hover(
    function() {
        J(this).addClass("hover");
    },
    function() {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            off.apply(that);
        }, 500);
    }
);
```

NB: don't use string parameters to `setTimeout()` !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this` is referring to something different in the scope fo the timeout-callback.

The simplest solution would be to provide the old scope using [jQuery.proxy([function],[scope])](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var f = function(){
                console.log(this.id);
            };

            $(function() {
                $("div").click(function () {
                    setTimeout($.proxy(f,this), 1000);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="a">a</div>
        <div id="b">b</div>
    </body>
</html>
```